# How to import to selenium webdriver project in eclipse ide a firefox profile in order to commit it to svn/git and use it from other machines?

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, svn, selenium

I have created a firefox profile with custom settings and I want to import it into a selenium project so I can commit it to repository and use from other machines when running tests, but I didn't succeed. It is possible to use profiles in projects not only local but on git/svn repository?

Answer (score 0):

A firefox profile is simply a directory with an arbitrary file structure.  So **yes**, it is possible.

If you need to use the profile, you'll need to add it to your project directory somewhere, maybe something like:

```
src/resources/java/
  firefox/
    profile/
```

and have that added via `git add src/resources/java/firefox`

Once there, you'll need to use that directory for the firefox profile.

Comment: That's how I tried, but I failed. I created the profile and I imported the folder into the project, but the custom firefox profile didn't show up. I was trying this workaround for an application side bug, someone forgot a "\n" after xlsx mime type (it looks like: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\n ) and also used some other inexisting mime type, and I can't download it automatically setting the profile preferences from code, for the first time the dialog box shows up on download. Thanks anyway!